# automatic capturing top output by cronjob CENTOS 6.5 x86_64

Tags: shell-script, ssh, scripting, top

I have this command:

```
top -n 14400 -a -b -d 1 > /toplogfile.txt
```

I want to make a script which is run by `cron` every day to capture top output, and if it is possible `gzip` the output file after the script finished.

How can I implement this?

Comment: you would need another cron job if you want to gzip things **after** this first script finishes. Why not do it in the same script?

Answer (score 0):

`top -n 1` will run top for 1 iteration.  You can direct that output to a file and compress it using a simple shell script like this:
`top -b -n 1 | gzip -c > top_output.gz`

`top -b` specifies that you want top to run in "Batch Mode" which eliminates all of the control characters that top normally uses to format the output.

`-n 1` tell top to run 1 iteration

`gzip -c` tells gzip to compress the data it is being sent

Comment: I am quite new in linux, I do not know how to write this script at all. Do I have to put this command into an `file.sh` and set a cron job to execute this file in a specific time?

Comment: I must have missed the command you put in the OP, but the -a option isn't valid on the version of top I use.  You could put this command directly into cron, but I would say that is bad practice, if this is something you want to run 14400 iterations of.  It seems like you are trying to gather system statistics and I am sure there would be a better way of doing so than using `top`.

Comment: -a is tested on my configuration, it sorts the process list by memory usage

Comment: @Davis Wilkins you are right. Sometimes one of the processes use up almost 50% of my memory, but it runs only for a short time. This drops out the majority of usefull cache. I want to catch this process. You have better way to do this?

Comment: `ps aux --sort -rss` will give you a list of the running processes sorted by memory usage, it's much more efficient than running top continuously.    If you really needed to you could run this once a second and gzip the output as above to try to catch the culprit